# Prey anti-theft configuration on Debian

Tags: debian, configuration

I would like to protect my laptop from thieves. I would configure Prey, but I can't find any tutorial for Debian/Ubuntu users. I tried to go to the control panel on the project, but whenever I try to add a device, the server redirect me to download page. I have no idea how to go ahead. Who can help me? I have installed prey from the repository of Debian Wheezy. I found the configuration file, but I have no ideas on how to configure it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://panel.preyproject.com/login and register for an account.
A free account will allow you to track three devices.
After registering and logging in, you will find an api key on your account
page. Add the api key in the config file /etc/prey/config.
Then just be patient. 
The default install on Debian (jessie in my case)
runs every 20 minutes. You can change this in /etc/cron.d/prey if you wish.
But if you just wait, you will find the device announced on your Prey page.
The device key will be filled in automatically in the config file.